# How can I make inferences about individuals from aggregated data?

Tags: logistic, choice-modeling

Say I am trying to run a logistic regression on an individual's choice between objects A and B based on some vector of characteristics.

My dataset, however, only happens to have the proportion of people who chose A and the proportion of people who chose B in different countries and a vector of aggregate characteristics of the individuals in that country. Is there a way to identify the effects of these characteristics on an individual's choice?

Comment: No, it's not possible to go back from aggregated to individual data.

Comment: Do you also have access to the vector of characteristics for the individual you want to identify the effects on, or do you only have the aggregate characteristics of the individuals in each country?

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like this problem is an example of *ecological inference*.

[Gary King](https://gking.harvard.edu/) provides this definition in lecture slides: "[Advanced Quantitative Research Methodology Lecture
Notes: Ecological Inference](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/seitlk1p.pdf)" January 28, 2012

> Ecological Inference is the process of using aggregate (i.e.,
> “ecological”) data to infer discrete individual-level relationships of
> interest when individual-level data are not available.

Gary King cautions that, if you can avoid making ecological inference, you'll be much better off! The reason ecological inference is risky is [as Utobi states](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/613136/22311): the problem is under-specified.

That said, some problems are intractable without attempting ecological inference. For instance, ballots are secret, so estimating how voting totals (an aggregate in a geographic area) break down along demographic attributes (a quality of an individual) is a problem for ecological inference. Gary King is a proponent of the *tomography* method for ecological inference.

Gary King. *A Solution to the Ecological Inference Problem: Reconstructing Individual Behavior from Aggregate Data.*
Princeton University Press, 1997.

Comment: (+1) for the nice explanation. In addition, I'm happy to see that I'm not the only one who thinks this question doesn't deserve the close votes.

Comment: @utobi Thanks! (+1) to you as well. It seems that the close votes are requests for clarity. I suppose everyone has a different threshold for "this question is clear enough to be answerable."

Comment: Sure, that's fair!

Comment: I have seem methods like this being applied to re-analyse studies with few individuals, e.g., https://hackernoon.com/introducing-sprite-and-the-case-of-the-carthorse-child-58683c2bfeb.

Answer (score 7):

This is mostly an expanded version of my comment. It's not possible to go backwards from aggregated to individual data. Indeed, suppose variable $\bar x$ for country $i$, takes on value $4$. Assume there are three individuals $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$. Then for the three individuals, we could either choose $x_1=2, x_2= 6, x_3 = 4$ or $x_1=6, x_2=2, x_3=4$ or any other conforming partition. So we would end up with a dataset that doesn't necessarily coincide with the original one.

Comment: Why do you need to choose any values for $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$, respectively? I don't see your point.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye because this is what the OP is asking: how to impute values for the individuals based on aggregated (average) data. Mine shows what could happen in an example of three individuals being imputed.